# Anti-Aircraft capabilities of Islamic State

Tags: armed-conflict, military, islamic-state

Throughout the rapid spread of [Islamic State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_State_of_Iraq_and_the_Levant) (IS) [they have captured much American equipment](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/sep/08/isis-jihadis-using-arms-troop-carriers-supplied-by-us-saudi-arabia) and also Syrian equipment. I understand some of that equipment has been too advanced for IS to operate such as a [Syrian aircraft](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/islamic-state-isis-flaunts-captured-syrian-fighter-jets-in-video-showing-massacre-9720471.html).

IS would have had to at-least attempt to shoot down a US or its allies aircraft.

I've had difficulty discerning their anti-aircraft capabilities.

Have there been and reputable sources with this kind of information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a political question.

Comment: They might, although very doubtful, be able to shoot down an AC-130 or A-10, if the latter (which are designed for close air support and provide great fire power) are not shooting at them. But most multi-role fighter jets are supersonic nowadays, let alone Russian [strategic bombers like the Tu-22M](http://www.military.com/video/operations-and-strategy/air-strikes/6-russian-tu-22m3-bombers-slam-isis/5081291827001). So, no